# How to initialize an ifstream object in class constructor?

Tags: c++

I am aware that I can initialize an object of type `ifstream` like : 
`std::ifstream ifs ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);`

But let's say I have a class which needs to have ifstream object as a member of the class:

```
class A
{
private:
std::ifstream file;
}
```

How should I go about initializing this object in the classes' constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Add a constructor with an initializer list :

```
class A
{
    private:
        std::ifstream file;

    public:
        A()
        : file("test.txt", std::ifstream::in)
        {
        }
};
```